# Why UIViewController and UIView subclass UIResponder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

Looking at Apple [GLPaint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code.

I see that both PaintingViewController and PaintingView implement

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

Why is duality? Generally speaking, shouldn't only the UIView be responsible for handling the touch events generated by the hardware? as explained in [The Runtime Interaction Model for Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW42)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is one simple example:

Imagine you have a `presentedController`. Then you don't want the `presentingController` to handle touch events even if it's still visible.

View controller hierarchy is VERY important in event delivery.

See the note in `UIViewController` documentation:

> A view controller is tightly bound to the views it manages and takes part in the responder chain used to handle events. View controllers are also UIResponder objects and are inserted into the responder chain between the view controller’s root view and that view’s superview, which typically belongs to a different view controller. If none of the view controller’s views handle an event, the view controller has the option of handling the event or passing it along to the superview.

Comment: EDIT: So basically what this allows is defining a UIView that will "catch" the responder region but won't handle the event, passing it to the controller? What's the design architecture reason supporting this case? won't the presentedController always have a UIView property that will be able to handle the first responder event?

Comment: @MaximVeksler Yes, but you don't want unhandled events to be passed up. That's the whole point of having a controller responder there. It can decide whether events should go up or not. Compare with `UINavigationController`. When an event is not handled by the current view controller, it can still be handled by the navigation controller itself. The decision is a decision of the view controller, not of the view hierarchy.

Comment: Now this makes sense, it's a decision cross point. The controller in the MVP model is responsible for making the "choose" about what events are stopped and what are passed along. Thanks for working with me to clear this :)